# Help me please with reverb in noise reduction

Tags: noise, reverb, reduction

I'm running cool edit pro 2.1 and when I do the noise reduction I'm getting a lot of reverb.  I've been working on fixing it to no avail.  Any ideas I am running a b1 mic and a 802 mixer

Comment: Hm. I don't have any clue why reverb should occur. Can you post audio examples of that strange effect and the original recording?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have selected some of the wanted audio while analyzing. You should take a quiet part of the track with pure noise to analyze, then after analyzing apply the noise reduction to the whole track (or the section you want filtered).

See page 87 to 89 of the [Audition manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/audition/cs/using/audition_cs5.5_help.pdf). It has not changed much since Adobe have purchased Cool Edit Pro. The following is quoted from page 88:

> 1. In the Waveform Editor, select a range that contains only noise and is at least half a second long. To select noise in a specific
>      frequency range, use the Marquee Selection tool. (See “Select spectral
>      ranges” on page 39.)
> 2. Choose Effects
>
>    - Noise Reduction/Restoration
>    - Capture Noise Print.
> 3. In the Editor panel, select the range from which you want to remove noise.
> 4. Choose Effects
>
>    - Noise Reduction/Restoration
>    - Noise Reduction.
> 5. Set the desired options.

Another cause could be too high FFT sizes. Good settings range from 4096 to 8192.

Here's another quote from the manual:

> FFT Size Determines how many individual frequency bands are analyzed.
>   This option causes the most drastic changes in quality. The noise in
>   each frequency band is treated separately, so with more bands, noise
>   is removed with finer frequency detail. Good settings range from 4096
>   to 8192.
>
> Fast Fourier Transform size determines the tradeoff between frequency-
>   and time-accuracy. Higher FFT sizes might cause swooshing or
>   reverberant artifacts, but they very accurately remove noise
>   frequencies. Lower FFT sizes result in better time response (less
>   swooshing before cymbal hits, for example), but they can produce
>   poorer frequency resolution, creating hollow or flanged sounds.

Answer (score 0):

normally a noise reduction plug in won't introduce 'reverb' it could however enhance the perception of the reverb/roomnoises. 
In what type of room are you recording and what is the source?
What type of noise reduction are you using: are you using any expanders or multiband compressors?
If you compress recordings too hard it will enhance background noise and also reverb from the recording.

Comment: The OP may be referring to that watery, artifacty-sounding-reverb-quality.  The rounded hollowness.

Comment: @Stavrosound  Yes, this sounds to me like when you hammer Waves X-noise too hard on something and it starts to sound like it's adding short reflections or reverb.  Never used cool edit pro though, *shrug